# Displaying UL data in 3 uneven columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query that I am saving to a variable to output on the page. I have the data in an unordered list, but I am trying to split the data into three columns using 3 unordered lists floated left. Here is my current code:

```
        $sqlCommand = 
           "SELECT  list_specialty.id, list_specialty.specialty  FROM list_specialty
            ORDER BY list_specialty.specialty ASC";
        $query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));

        $specialtyDisplay = '';

        $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        $split = intval($num/3); //number of items in every column

        $i = 0;

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $specialtyid = $row["id"];
            $specialtyname = $row["specialty"];

            $specialtyDisplay .= 
                '<li><a href="doctor.php?specialty=' . $specialtyid . '">' . $specialtyname . '</a></li>';
            $i++;
            if ($i == $split) {
                $specialtyDisplay .= '</ul> <ul>';
                $i = 0;
            }

        }
```

This code works GREAT as long as my data is exactly divisible by 3 (equal columns).
However, when my total number of rows is not divisible by 3, the above code won't work.

I need a solution that will balance the columns, so I can have either 3 equal columns, one extra element in the first column, or one extra element in the first and second column.

What do I need to change in my code to account for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

1. set `$split` to the length of the longest column
2. rows have 0, 1 or 2 columns that are longer by one element. -> `$longcols = $num % 3`
3. substract 1 from `$split` when column number `$longcols` is printed (unless all columns have equal length)

Implemented in the code:

```
$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$split = ceil($num/3); // 1.

$i = 0;
$col = 1; //for counting columns
$longcols = $num % 3; // 2.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $specialtyid = $row["id"];
    $specialtyname = $row["specialty"];

    $specialtyDisplay .= 
        '<li><a href="doctor.php?specialty=' . $specialtyid . '">' . $specialtyname . '</a></li>';
    $i++;
    if ($i == $split) {
        $specialtyDisplay .= '</ul> <ul>';

        if( $longcols != 0 && $longcols == $col ) { $split--; } // 3.
        $i = 0;
        $col++; //increase columns count
    }

}
```

The lines with comments are those that I have changed/inserted.

Comment: This works! Thank you! Just a note to anyone else who may see this, there was one typo in the above code. This line:
`$longcols = $num % 3 // 2.` is missing a semicolon after the 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to support better browsers, you can use [CSS 3 Multicolumns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). It doesn't require you to split. Just CSS does the magic.

```
div#multicolumn {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

#### Screenshot:

[CSS3 MultiColumn http://css.flepstudio.org/images/css3/css3-multi-column.jpg](http://css.flepstudio.org/images/css3/css3-multi-column.jpg)

Comment: I need to split the columns into separate ULs for another script. I personally prefer the CS3 solution, but I'm also having to support IE6 (YUCK! but it's at client's request).

Comment: Ha ha... I understand. Why don't you use `mysql_num_rows()` and predetermine the values and split?

Comment: I am using `$num = mysqli_num_rows($query);` but I don't know what you mean by "predetermine the values and split". I can't predetermine the length of the query result, as it will be changing. I may have 20 values to split into 3 columns, or 33, or 50.

Comment: Anyways you need to leave one or two rows empty right? No predetermination stuff. Well, am not able to explain you clearly. Lemme put it in answer. :)